# Convert string to json doesn't work java

Tags: java, json, string, parsing

I have a problem with convert string to json.
Namely, my json string is:

```
{"serverId":2,"deviceId":736,"analysisDate":"2017-05-11T07:20:27.713Z","eventType":"Logs","eventAttributes":[{"name":"level","value":"INFO"},{"name":"type","value":"Video Blocked On"},{"name":"cameraId","value":"722"},{"name":"userId","value":"1"}]}
```

My code:

```
    try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("eventAttributes");
        System.out.println("ARRAY: " + array);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(array.getJSONObject(i));
            System.out.println("OBJ: " + obj);

        }
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    }
```

System.out.println array is:

```
[{"name":"level","value":"INFO"},{"name":"type","value":"Video Blocked On"},{"name":"cameraId","value":"722"},{"name":"userId","value":"1"}]
```

but if I print obj is "{}", four times. So it is correct, because array has 4 elements, but why it is empty object? I'm using org.json.

Thanks

Comment: try `obj.toString();` api.

Comment: @ShubhamNaik why do you think that would work?

Comment: It is supposed to print object description, maybe we can get some detail about what is happening.

Comment: check toString() method of JSONObject class. Its build a string object then return.

Comment: OP why do you do `new JSONObject(array.getJSONObject(i));` ? `array.getJSONObject(i)` already returns a `JSONObject`

Comment: @ShubhamNaik whay do you think there is a difference between `System.out.println("OBJ: " + obj);` and `System.out.println("OBJ: " + obj.toString ());` ?

Comment: @Scary Wombat thanks, it works! :)

Comment: @ScaryWombat got it, will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array.getJSONObject(i)` is already returning you an object of type `JSONObject` you dont need to pass it to constructor of `JSONObject` class.

simply write

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
   System.out.println("OBJ: " + obj);
}
...
```

Comment: In my answer I've explained why the original code behaves the way it does, as well as linking to the source code of the constructor being called. (It looks like the version available from Android, which is what you linked to, does not include that constructor.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I wasn't sure which library OP is using. Anyways thanks for explaining it out. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Yes, I see, thanks a lot. :) Unfortunately, I can not vote for your answer, because I dont have 15 reputation points. :(

Answer (score 4):

You're calling the [`JSONObject(Object)`](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/f12fa9ba5f760a01f635a5334c2ba44e24424c86/JSONObject.java#L276) constructor, passing in a `JSONObject` (the element in the array). That constructor is documented as:

> Construct a JSONObject from an Object using bean getters. It reflects on
>   all of the public methods of the object. For each of the methods with no
>   parameters and a name starting with `"get"` or
>   `"is"` followed by an uppercase letter, the method is invoked,
>   and a key and the value returned from the getter method are put into the
>   new JSONObject. [...]

Now `JSONObject` itself doesn't have anything that fits a bean getter, so you end up with no keys. You *don't* want to treat the `JSONObject` as a bean.

That's why your *current* code doesn't work. To fix it, just don't call the constructor - instead, use the fact that the array element is already a `JSONObject`:

```
JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
```

Output with that change:

```
OBJ: {"name":"level","value":"INFO"}
OBJ: {"name":"type","value":"Video Blocked On"}
OBJ: {"name":"cameraId","value":"722"}
OBJ: {"name":"userId","value":"1"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you consider following example you can do it in 3 ways :

```
jsonString = {
   "name"  : "John",
   "sport" : "Soccer",
   "age"   : 25,
   "id"    : 100,
   "score" : [ 2, 1, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1]
}
```

**String to JSON Object using GSON**

```
Gson g = new Gson();
Player p = g.fromJson(jsonString, Player.class)
```

You can also convert Java object to JSON by using method **toJson()**

```
String str = g.toJson(p);
```

**JSON String to Java object using JSON-Simple**

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringToParse);
```

**String to JSON - Jackson Example**

```
Player john = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Player.class);
```